# WSE3 Destination vs URL

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wse3.0

I have a vendor telling me that the SOAP header should not have https in it, but that we can still communicate via SSL.  Our concern is that we want to communicate via SSL and that their sample code is causing it not to happen.

In their sample program, they provide this code:

```
    if (valservice.Url.StartsWith("https"))
    {
        valservice.Destination = new Microsoft.Web.Services3.Addressing.EndpointReference(
            new Uri(valservice.Url.Replace("https:", "http:")));
    }
```

From breaking it down into smaller steps, and adding some debug, it seems that when you change the destination, that the URL automatically changes.

```
if (valservice.Url.StartsWith("https"))
{
    // fix the endpoint just in case (usually not necessary)
    //original code is just this next line 
    //valservice.Destination = new Microsoft.Web.Services3.Addressing.EndpointReference(
    //    new Uri(valservice.Url.Replace("https:", "http:")));


    //test code 
    string holdOriginalURL = valservice.Url;

    Response.WriteLine("1 URL=" + valservice.Url);
    Response.WriteLine("1 Destination=" + valservice.Destination);
    Response.WriteLine("1 Destination.Address.Value=" + valservice.Destination.Address.Value);
    Response.WriteLine("1 Destination.TransportAddress=" + valservice.Destination.TransportAddress);

    //test 
    string newURL = valservice.Url;
    newURL = newURL.Replace("https:", "http:"); 
    //valservice.Destination = new Microsoft.Web.Services3.Addressing.EndpointReference(
    //    new Uri(newURL));
    Microsoft.Web.Services3.Addressing.EndpointReference tempEndPoint = new Uri(newURL);
    valservice.Destination = tempEndPoint; 
    //valservice.Url = holdOriginalURL; 
    Response.WriteLine("2 URL=" + valservice.Url);
    Response.WriteLine("2 Destination=" + valservice.Destination);
    Response.WriteLine("2 Destination.Address.Value =" + valservice.Destination.Address.Value);
    Response.WriteLine("2 Destination.TransportAddress=" + valservice.Destination.TransportAddress);
}
```

Output:

```
1 URL=https://someaddress.net/orgid/SomeApplication/SomeService.asmx
1 Destination.Address.Value=https://someaddress.net/orgid/SomeApplication/SomeService.asmx
1 Destination.TransportAddress=https://someaddress.net/orgid/SomeApplication/SomeService.asmx

2 URL=http://someaddress.net/orgid/SomeApplication/SomeService.asmx
2 Destination.Address.Value=http://someaddress.net/orgid/SomeApplication/SomeService.asmx
2 Destination.TransportAddress=http://someaddress.net/orgid/SomeApplication/SomeService.asmx
```

**Question:** 
Is it possible to have a different URL in the destination than the URL? 
If so how?

Also, if I reset the URL after update the Destination, the Destination also gets changed.  Seems like the two are somehow linked to each other and cannot be different?

Thanks,

Neal Walters

Update 1: Some research indicates that the vendor might be able to add the **SoapActor attribute** to their site.

When we have https in the URL, they give this error:

> The  header must match the
>   actor URI value of the web service. 
>   The actor URI value can be explicitly
>   specified using SoapActorAttribute on
>   the ASMX class.  In the absence of the
>   attribute, the actor URI is assumed to
>   be equal to the HTTP Request Url of
>   the incoming message.  The  header
>   received contained
>   "https://somesite.net/orgid/SomeApp/SomeService.asmx"
>   while the receiver is expecting
>   "http://somesite.net/orgid/SomeApp/SomeService.asmx".

Comment: Is there some reason you're using WSE? Did you know it's obsolete?

Comment: Does my vendor want to keep up with the times is the question? According to Microsoft, WCF is "wire compatible" with WSE. Not when you call them and push them for details, only if vendor turns on "SSL Required" in their IIS. Nasty stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vendor's sample was indeed wrong and not using SSL. 
The solution was to add the "VIA" parameter to the constructor of the endpoint:

```
 valservice.Destination =
            new Microsoft.Web.Services3.Addressing.EndpointReference(
                new Uri(valservice.Url.Replace("https:", "http:")), 
                new Uri(valservice.Url));
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.services3.addressing.endpointreference.via.aspx